# reading parameter value with regex in shell

Tags: regex, grep, sh

I want to simply read this file

```
FOO=1
BAR=/^@djrhaali$$sdf
```

with some shell function like this:

```
FOO=$(GetParam "FOO")
BAR=$(GetParam "BAR")
```

so to retrieve the content of each config parameter in the file (after the "="), I need something like:

```
GetParam() {
   cat  myFile | grep '^${$1}=' | grep -oP '(?<${$1}=).*'
}
```

which gives me

`grep: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator)`

---

Note:

I'm using grep from the git bash (grep (GNU grep) 2.27)

Comment: Also, always use https://shellcheck.net for a first analysis of what could be wrong. Not all errors mentioned are necessarily errors (especially the Perl Regex), but it is always good practice.

Comment: I'm using shell in declarative pipeline in jenkins so I was wrapping the function with ```def GetParam(x)```

Comment: Why don't you just source the file?  eg `. myfile`

Comment: i want to use the parameter value as environment variable in jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments in shell aren't named as in other languages like C. They are handled by special variables that represent the argument list. For e.g. `"$@"`  refers to the entire list of arguments. So the first argument passed is named `$1`, `$2` upto the last argument.

Also variables in shell are *not* interpolated under single quotes. You need to double quote them for it to expand.

The reported problem of missing terminator is because of an incorrect PCRE look-behind regex, that was missing a `=` symbol

```
GetParam() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && { printf 'arg empty\n' >&2; }
    grep "${1}=" file | grep -oP "(?<=${1}=).*"
    #                               ^^^^ missing = symbol
}
```

Look at the usage of `grep` on the input file directly avoiding useless invocation of `cat`. Avoiding multiple `grep` invocations, you can simply use `awk` for this as

```
GetParam() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && { printf 'arg empty\n' >&2; }
    awk -F= -v var="$1" '$1 == var { print $2 }' file 
}
```

With this definitions, you can now use the functions as

```
fooval=$(GetParam FOO)
barval=$(GetParam BAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another proper approach, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s *associative array* :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    arr[$key]="$value"
done < InputFile

getParam() { echo "${arr[$1]}";  }
```

Now using declarated function :

```
getParam foo
1
```

and

```
getParam bar
/^@djrhaali$$sdf
```

### Notes :

- in bash, function call are not like `func(1)` but `func 1`
- your solution using grep is not as reliable as this solution
- no need to do `cat file | grep foobar` but only `grep foobar file`
- avoid using UPPER CASE variables, they are reserved for system use
- learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

  > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
  >   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
  >   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
  >   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words